# Filter stopped working when used with OmniFaces FacesViews

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters, omnifaces

I'm using Glassfish 4.1.1, JSF Mojarra 2.2, omnifaces 2.4, primefaces 6.0 and EE7.
I have the following LoginFilter:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "LoginFilter", urlPatterns = {"/secure/*"})
public class LoginFilter extends HttpFilter {
...
}
```

I started using Omnifaces ExtensionlessURLs and now the filter no longer runs. My *web.xml*:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
    <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCANNED_VIEWS_ALWAYS_EXTENSIONLESS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_EXTENSION_ACTION</param-name>
    <param-value>REDIRECT_TO_EXTENSIONLESS</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My request to */secure/home* doesnt change to */home* conveniently. I do not want to change my *urlPatterns* to "/*". 
What should I do for my filter rerun with Extensionless?

Comment: I posted an answer but I removed it as this is after all not the default behavior based on information provided so far. Perhaps you have set the `org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_DISPATCH_METHOD` context param to `FORWARD`? If so, this means that the filters should be configured to listen on `dispatcherTypes=FORWARD`.

Comment: Hi. Thx for reply. No, I dont have this parameter set in my web.xml.
I added this parameter with the DO_FILTER value but without success.